# Force on moving conductor in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

When the conductor is moving,
my textbook considers only the electrons as moving charge.

However bonded ions stuck in the lattice are also moving...
Why don't these ions contribute to the mechanical force **iLxB** on conductor ?

> Moving Conductor. When a conductor begins to move at speed v through a
> magnetic field, its conduction electrons do also. They are then like
> the moving conduction electrons in the current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, since it's always quite a pain (at least, to me) when we have to deal with moving charges and moving conductors in electromagnetism.

The answer is that the positive charges do the same motion as the negative charges, except for their relative velocity, i.e. the velocity of the free charges. Using Lorentz's force on a pair of particles with opposite charges, we get

$\mathbf{F} = q_{-} \mathbf{v}_{-} \times \mathbf{b} + q_{+} \mathbf{v}_{+} \times \mathbf{b} = q_{-} ( \mathbf{v}_{-} - \mathbf{v}_{+}) \times \mathbf{b}$

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure I fully understand.. i have two situations:    
1) When the conductor is stationary in a magnetic field, but current is there: then clearly only the electrons are moving. So the magnetic force acts on electrons; then these electrons push the conductor; and the conductor wire as a whole moves/bends mechanically..(contd..)

Comment: 2) When the conductor is moving in a magnetic field, no current: then both electrons and bonded ions are moving. So it seems the magnetic force must act on both electrons and ions...?

Comment: if the conductor is moving at constant velocity, both electrons and bonded ions are also moving at the same velocity right?

Comment: if both have same speed, then 

$$\mathbf{F} = q_{-} \mathbf{v}_{-} \times \mathbf{b} + q_{+} \mathbf{v}_{+} \times \mathbf{b} = q_{-} ( \mathbf{v}_{-} - \mathbf{v}_{+}) \times \mathbf{b} =q_{-} ( 0 - 0) \times \mathbf{b}  = 0 $$

Comment: what am i missing?

Comment: They don't have the same speed, if electric current is different from zero. We can think at net positive charges constrained to move withe conductor, while net free negative charges can move freely in the conductor itself, producing the electric current. You can think at $\mathbf{v}_{-} - \mathbf{v}_{+}$ as the relative velocity of the free negative charges w.r.t. the conductor (and the bounded charges)

Comment: Ok what about the case when current is 0, but the whole conductor is mechanically moving in magnetic field. Would the magnetic forces acting on electrons and bonded ions cancel out?

Comment: No current means no relative velocity between the free charges and the conductor, $\mathbf{v}_{+} = \mathbf{v}_{-}$. In absence of net charges, you get  $\mathbf{F} = q_{-} (\mathbf{v}_{-} - \mathbf{v}_{+}) \times \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{0}$

Answer (score 1):

Actually when a rod is in magnetic field there is induced charge which is due to the length contraction of rods.
This isn't usually taught in high schools.
But they overall nullify it giving the result IL×B
You may check Feyman lecture of this in more detail.